# hide the "buy now " button if quantity is out of stock "

Tags: addtocart, product-view

i followed this blog to display the BUY NOW BUTTON

http://blog.fusedwebspace.co.uk/adding-buy-now-button-to-magento-1-9-that-skips-the-shopping-cart/

i displayed as like in the  below link : 
i want to hide the buy now button if quantity is "out - of -stock"

please help me to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($_product->isAvailable()) {
    ?>
    <button type=”button” title=”Buy Now” class=”button btn-cart” onclick=”setcheckoutLocation(‘<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>’)”><span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
    <?php      
}
```

will probably do it.